# Markers and the imagesc() function in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

How do you create a marker on a 2D image that is plotted using imagesc()? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You simply want to draw something over your image? Then you can just use hold on.

For example, this will draw a circle at the 10,10 pixel of the image.

```
imagesc(magic(24));
hold on
scatter(10,10);
```